# How to override scss variables for fonts?

Tags: css, sass, localization, font-family

Is there any way to override **scss variables** used for fonts. i have used font variables across the website and now i need to change the font specifically for a **localized website**.

i need to override using **:lang** attribute in html. is there any way to override variables or any implementation idea to achieve this. my idea is to achieve something like this. if this is achievable by any means we don't require to override in all places where this fonts are declared.

```
$primary-font: 'Roboto';
:lang('fr') { $primary-font: 'locator' }
```

Added [codepen](https://codepen.io/yoyo/pen/MWVOQaE) of what i am trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to test this but given it compiles to a CSS key value pair can you use

```
'locator !important'
```

Not ideal coding I know but it might work

Comment: No this won't work. i have tried this here [link](https://codepen.io/yoyo/pen/MWVOQaE). 

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the newly assigned value as font-family as follow.

```css
$primary-font : 'Locator';

* {
  font-family: $primary-font;
}

[lang="fr"] {
  $primary-font: 'oswald';
   font-family : $primary-font;
}
```

```html
<div lang="fr">
  <p>test frace</p>
</div>

  <p>test normal</p>
```

Comment: Yes this can be done.

But what i am trying to solve is we have called font-family across multiple components. we should not add this new font-family to override again and again in all components. 

is it no other way to switch fonts only by changing variables or some-other conditions in scss.